# JAVA applet- Gold Rush

Tags: java, applet

I have this assignment: 
Implement
a
small
game
in
which:

1. There
   are
   two
   islands
   in
   a
   sea.
2. A
   boat
   needs
   to
   travel
   from
   one
   island
   to
   another
   island
   to
   gather
   as
   much
   gold
   as
   possible
   and
   come
   back.
3. The
   boat
   can
   be
   navigated
   using
   the
   arrow
   keys.
4. A
   boat
   cannot
   sail
   through
   an
   island.
5. There
   are
   sea
   mines
   along
   the
   way
   moving
   at
   random.
6. The
   mines
   do
   not
   go
   through
   the
   islands
   as
   they
   drift
   around.
7. If
   the
   boat
   hits
   a
   mine,
   it
   is
   destroyed.
   Each
   boat
   has
   three
   lives.
8. It
   takes
   time
   for
   the
   gold
   to
   be
   fully
   loaded
   into
   the
   boat.
   This
   time
   is
   approximately
   three
   seconds.
   If
   a
   boat
   doesn’t
   wait
   this
   long,
   it
   is
   partially
   loaded
   with
   gold.
9. The
   same
   happens
   for
   unloading.
10. The
    game
    ends
    after
    you
    fully
    unload
    five
    times,
    or
    your
    life
    ends.
11. There
    are
    three
    difficulties
    for
    the
    game:
    Easy,
    medium
    and
    difficult.
    An
    easy
    game
    has
    fewer
    mines
    than
    a
    medium
    game,
    and
    a
    medium
    game
    has
    fewer
    mines
    than
    a
    difficult
    game.

That is what I have till now:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GoldRush extends Applet {

int boatx=125;
int boaty= 270;
int lifes = 3;
int gold1=0;
int gold2=20;
int option;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public void init()
{

        setSize(900, 500);

        Object[] options = {"Easy", "Meduim","Difficult"};
         option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this,"Choose a difficulty ","Gold Rush",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,options,options[2]);
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener());
        setFocusable(true);

    }

public  void paint(Graphics g) {

  Image back,boat,bomb,gold;

  back = getImage("back.jpg");
  boat = getImage("boat.jpg");
  bomb = getImage("bomb.jpg");
  gold = getImage("gold.jpg");
  g.drawImage(back, 0, 0, null);
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.drawString("Lifes: "+ lifes, 10, 20);
  g.drawString("Gold on Your ISland: "+ gold1, 10, 40);
  g.drawString("Gold on the other Island: "+ gold2, 10, 60);

  if(boatx >=125 && boatx <= 640&& boaty >= 2 && boaty <= 450){
      g.drawImage(boat, boatx, boaty, null);
  }else {
      if(boatx<125) boatx=125;
      if(boatx>640) boatx=640;
      if(boaty<2) boaty=2;
      if(boaty>450) boaty=450;
      g.drawImage(boat, boatx, boaty, null);
  }



  if (option == 0){
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);

  }
  else if (option == 1){
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);

  }
  else if (option == 2){
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);
       g.drawImage(bomb, (int)(145 + (Math.random() * (601 - 145))),(int)(190 + (Math.random() * (700 - 190))) , null);

  }


}



public Image getImage(String name){
URL imgUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/"+name);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
return icon.getImage();
}  
    public void up(){

        boaty= boaty-5;
        repaint();  
}  
  public void down(){

        boaty= boaty+5;
        repaint();  
}  
  public void left(){
    if(boatx >= 125)
        boatx= boatx-5;
        repaint();  
}
  public void right(){

        boatx= boatx+5;
        repaint();  
}
class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
    public KeyListener(){

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.keyPressed(e);
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT : left();break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: right();break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP: up();break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: down(); break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
        }
    }
}


}
```

I don't know how to do number 8, where I check for if the boat stays 3 secs to fully load the gold. Could you please help me with that?

I would appreciate it ;)

Comment: It sounds like you need a timer that starts counting when the boat is loaded and stops either after three seconds or when the user moves it.

Comment: get the  lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() when you start loading the gold (e.g. you're near the island) and check when you stop loading (leave the island) if System.currentTimeMillis()  - lStartTime > 3000, the is fully loaded, else partially.

Comment: Basically, you need to devise some kind of (possibly random) fill time.  So when the boat "lands", you would raise a flag.  Based on the amount the boat an carry and the fill time, you can determine how much gold will be packed onto the boat on each turn that the boat sits on the shore.  Unless absolutely required I would move you game of to the Swing API, starting by using a `JPanel` as your base component and overriding the `paintComponent` method.  This can then be added to a `JApplet`.  This will take care of any flickering issues you might have...

Comment: I'd also recommend using the Key Bindings API over `KeyListener`, but that's just me...

Comment: I figured it out , Thanks but can you help me understand how to use javadoc cause I keep losing marks for not using it and all I know about it is that I should add comments and it will be generate in html page... if you could help that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Your boat has position with a x and y coordinate. If you island is created, you calculate/read out the coordinates which locate the island. Then after every move of the boat, you check if the boat is in the  region of your island ( or close to it). If so, you start a timer which "tranfers" the gold to your boat.

Comment: I figured it out , Thanks but can you help me understand how to use javadoc cause I keep losing marks for not using it and all I know about it is that I should add comments and it will be generate in html page... if you could help that would be great